# How much memory RethinkDB need?

Tags: digital-ocean, rethinkdb, horizon

I have a horizon app running in digitalocean on 1GB RAM machine.
I try to set permissions with:

```
hz set-schema ./.hz/schema.toml
```

but getting the following error:
error: rethinkdb stderr: warn: Cache size does not leave much memory for server and query overhead (available memory: 779 MB).

Tried to use "cache-size" option in rethinkdb config file, but still getting the same error (I restarted the service).

Do I need to enlarge my digitalocean machine or I can do something with the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to give RethinkDB more memory (I usually give it at least 2 gigs), but if your load is light that size should be fine.  I think the recommendation is to make the cache size about half your available memory, but you can also lower it if that turns out to be unstable.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. My problem that I can't change the cache-size following their instructions

Comment: Is the problem that the cache size doesn't change after setting it in the config file, or that it changes but you still get the warning?  If the latter, what are you changing it to?

Comment: It's the first. It doesn't change after setting it in the config file

Comment: Does it successfully change the cache size when you pass `--cache-size` on the command line?